# Two word navigation items are not fitting correctly, CSS solution?

Tags: html, css

Here is the site -->  http://ridgelandbaptist.radiantwebtools.com/

This screenshot, with commentary pretty much sums up the issue --> http://screencast.com/t/R4evQe4pq

Navigation items that take up 2 lines are taking up more space than I would desire.  I would like there to be a 20px space between the word and the white bar.  With the navigation items that are 2 lines or more, they are taking up more space.

Here is the selector which provides the padding.

```
 #template .header .navigation-module .horizontal ul.menu > li > a {
     height: 124px;
     border-right: 1px solid white;
     padding: 0 20px;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I cannot change the markup. Only CSS at my disposal here.

Help would be greatly appreciated here.  Let me know if I can provide any extra info.

Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think it looks pretty nice if you get rid of the max-width property for the nav items. At least in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `#template .header .navigation-module .horizontal ul.menu > li > a`, add this css:

`width: 1px;`

So that your CSS becomes:

```
#template .header .navigation-module .horizontal ul.menu > li > a {
    height: 124px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 1px;
}
```

When your span breaks to 2 lines, it is expanding to your max-width of the LI of 100px. Set the width to 1px on the A and it will suck all the extra space out.

Comment: No worries. If my answer worked, please don't forget to tick accept :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the widths to adjust based on text width + padding, try using `white-space: nowrap` on your nav items.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the size of your font. The font may not size in the "a" tag.

Or you make more wider or you step down to 1.8em (i try in the inspector) to down all the menu fonts.

So if you want two lines, is the text-align the problem.